# Between two date , how can i take all date with one id

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
empid   startdate      expirydate
18426   2018-01-01     2018-01-05
```

i am expecting :-

```
date          id
2018-01-01   18426  
2018-01-02   18426  
2018-01-03   18426  
2018-01-04   18426  
2018-01-05   18426
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: i am using sql server 2012

Answer (score 2):

You need `cte` with recursive way :

```
with t as (
     select empid, startdate, enddate
     from table
     union all
     select empid, dateadd(day, 1, startdate), enddate
     from t
     where stardate < enddate
)

select *
from t
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: it's working but i am getting this error.

Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 67
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: The OP originally had 2019, rather than 2018. if they do have dates with that big of a difference, then this'll fail, as the default max recursion is 100. Also, this method is actually a method of RBAR. :)

Comment: @SandeepSingh I think what you're asking for there, is a consultant. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/) or a [Tally Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/).

You can also do it on the fly. This example should get you on the right path:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date, @EndDate date;
SET @StartDate = '20180101';
SET @EndDate = '20190105';

WITH N AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) V(U)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2
         CROSS JOIN N N3
         CROSS JOIN N N4)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, I, @StartDate) AS [date]       
FROM Tally T
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, I, @StartDate) <= @EndDate;
```